# Performance Point Dasboard for a sharepoint Projects Task List?

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, tasks, performancepoint, bi

I have createed a "Projects Tasks List" in sharepoint with a couple of columns added for further detail.

I am looking to create a Dashboard with atleast three visual aid sections to improve better visibility across the board.

For Starters I would like to be able to display these at the least:

1. Section 1: Status indicator based on the number of active tasks within a project, number of on-target vs off-target tasks within a project.
2. A simple line graph/chart illustrating data from Section 1 data.

I would like to be able to apply a time filter so users can narrow their results based on a particular week, month or year.

I have not had the best of luck trying to find helpful resources. Any good information will be appreciated.

Note: We do not have project server. All this will be using the sharepoint Projects Tasks list as the datasource.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have to settle with a couple of KPI on a Status list :(